# Catalog Search returns 450 error

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

Magento Version: 2.4.3

Search Query: **https://siteurl/catalogsearch/result/?q=sku**

The search query works well but sometimes for certain product it returns 450 error.
[image]

Is there any solution?
Please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: can you check error logs?

Comment: I checked the logs, but there's nothing

Comment: Add this code in you index.php file for error log enable:- error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Yes, I know it. But it works on dev and it doesn't work on live